# Some applications lag in Ubuntu 18.04 installed on AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950x

Tags: 18.04, firefox, amd-processor, mozilla

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950x system. A few applications like Firefox, Thunderbird, and Terminal lag. For example, in both Firefox and Thunderbird, whenever I right click, it takes about 3-4 seconds for the list to appear. Also, in Firefox, whenever I click on an HTML drop-down list to see the context menu, I again have to wait for a few seconds to see the list. In Terminal, right clicking works fin, but whenever I press tab twice to see the list of options or to use autocomplete, it freezes from few seconds.

Here is what I get for `$ free -m`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          32085        3061       26536         172        2487       28525
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem magically disappeared. I have a dual display system. One is connected to the graphic card by a dp to mini-dp cable and the other one by an HDMI cable. The only two things that have changed are 1) I've changed the HDMI cable and 2) I changed the primary display to be monitor 1 rather than 2. I don't think these should have anything to do with my problem, but these are the only things I could think of that have changed.